# Change cell size of heatmap generated in ggplot R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

Here is a sample heatmap I made: [image]

```
    id<-c(1:10)
    var1<-c(rnorm(10,3,1))
    var2<-c(rnorm(10,5,1))
    dat<-data.frame(cbind(id,var1,var2))
    data<-melt(dat,id.var="id",value.var=c("var1","var2"))
    ggplot(data, aes(variable, id)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "gray", high = "black")
```

I want to change the size of each cell in the heat map. I want each cell to be a small square, something like: 
[image]

I have tried:

```
ggplot(data, aes(variable, id)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white",size=4) + scale_fill_gradient(low = "gray", high = "black")  

ggplot(data, aes(variable, id,height=200,width=200)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white",size=4) + scale_fill_gradient(low = "gray", high = "black")
```

But neither of them work.

Comment: Just add `+  coord_fixed()` Otherwise the tiles grow to take up all available area.

Comment: coord_fixed is indeed the way to go. It even has a `ratio` argument for if you don't want squares but rectangles with certain proportions.